# filter by price range and genre using vue js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i'm new to vue js and i'm trying to make two filters one by price range and the other by genre.
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code

```html
ul class="filter-wrapper">
  <li v-for="el in genreList" v-bind:key="el">
    <a
      href="#"
      data-filter=".el.toLowerCase()"
      onclick="genreFilter(el)"
     >{{ el }}</a>
   </li>
        <h3>Filter By Price Range</h3>
        <label for="vol">Price (between 0 and 3):</label>
        <input type="range" v-model="range" min="0" max="3" step="0.5" />
        Selected :
        {{
          range
        }}
        <h1 v-for="el in filterRestosByRange" v-bind:key="el">
          {{ el }}
        </h1>
      </ul>
```

```js
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      restoFeed: [],
      searchString: "",
      genre: ""
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.restoFeed = await api.getRestaurantsList();
  },
  computed: {
    filterRestosByRange: function() {
      return this.restoFeed.items.filter(function(item) {
        item.price_range > 0 && item.price_range < this.range ? item.name : "";
      });
    },
    filterProductsByCategory: function() {
      return this.restoFeed.items.filter(
        item => !item.genres.indexOf(this.genre)
      );
    }, `
```

Here is the API link : https://ufoodapi.herokuapp.com/unsecure/restaurants/

Comment: What's wrong? Do you get errors? Unwanted behavior?

Comment: No errors but i dont know why i didn't work

Answer (score 1):

While using filter make sure it returns a Boolean value

```
filterRestosByRange: function() {
      return this.restoFeed.items.filter(function(item) {
        return (item.price_range > 0 && item.price_range < this.range);
      });
    },
```

and it should be rendered like this

```
<h1 v-for="el in filterRestosByRange" v-bind:key="el">
          {{ el.name}}
        </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to write `range` in data property

```
data() {
    return {
      restoFeed: [],
      searchString: "",
      genre: "",
      range: ""
    };
  },
```

And for `computed` method you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814138/6345936